# With Amazon Web Services' RDS, should I increase the instance size and/or IOPS count to get better performance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I currently have a small MySQL RDS instance. It's for a webapp that on average does more reads than writes (maybe 75/25) with daily bursts of heavy writing. I set the database size at 305 GB after hearing about rumors of striping at 300 GB+.

What I'm wondering is what's the best way to improve performance?

1) Upgrade my instance size.
2) Increase allotted IOPS.
3) Or consider another strategy like a read replica.

For metrics, my write IOPS are very low. Typically, 25-50 with bursts of 100 and 200 at different times. Read IOPS never go hire that 50 and are usually much lower. Database CPU usage is usually in the 30-40% range except for bursts.

Answer (score 0):

Changing "Provisioned IOPS" is simply a config update and you can change it back if it doesn't help you so I'd try that first. If CPU at 30/40% seems a bit high you may want to try `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to debug any long-running queries, learn to know what's normal CPU usage for the machine in general (e.g. what happens during backups etc)